# Nautilus Extension to bring back annotations

Tags: gnome, nautilus

Nautilus used to have a tab for annotations (notes) for files.  I'd like to know whether is possible to bring it back via extensions.  If so, how? what documentation should I look at for writing my own extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [documentation available at archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20090418175132/http://www.campd.org/stuff/docs/extending-nautilus/NautilusExtensions.html).  Also check the [answer in a more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580206/nautilus-extensions-where-are-the-docs).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I still don't know how to add a tab and check the annotations, but this is something I can start with.